storing json list/array to MySQL with Laravel 11 api
I'm pretty new to laravel and I'm trying to find a better way to store a json list/array in mysql using the api. This is my current implementation of how I am able to get everything to work but I have to wonder if my lack of experience is blinding me from a cleaner solution and this would be a good way to learn.
Any thoughts?
Json sent from postman
[
    {"ItemNum":"01","ItemName":"Well Bourbon"},
    {"ItemNum":"016600000760","ItemName":"Rose's Grenadine 1L"},
    {"ItemNum":"02","ItemName":"Beam Apple"},
    {"ItemNum":"02835727","ItemName":"Cigs"},
    {"ItemNum":"029929115411","ItemName":"Licor 43 750mil"}
]

StoreInventoryRequest.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreInventoryRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, ValidationRule|array<mixed>|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {

        return [
            '*.ItemNum' => 'required|string',
            '*.ItemName' => 'required|string',

        ];
    }
}

InventoryController.php
    public function store(StoreInventoryRequest $request)
    {

        foreach ($request->validated() as $item)
        {

            $inventory = Inventory::create($item);

            InventoryResource::make($inventory);

        }
    }

InventoryResource.php
    class InventoryResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'ItemNum' => $this->ItemNum,
            'ItemName' => $this->ItemName
        ];

    }
}

Initally I used this to get a single json object to save but it does not work for a json list/array

    public function store(StoreInventoryRequest $request)
    {


            $inventory = Inventory::create($request->validated());

            return InventoryResource::make($inventory);

     }



what do you want to return back? your InventoryResource is not being used for anything

The tutorial I followed initially for storing the single json object returned a json of what was added to the database, I could see this being useful to tell the sender if something errored as was not added correctly.

If successful it would look exactly like what was sent
Also what do you mean about the InventoryResource not being used? Does that not save the data to the database?
I just realized I never included the InventoryResource.php and updated the initial question.

the resource is not the one saving data to the database. Also in your loop you are not doing anything with the InventoryResource::make call. If you want to return a list of created resources, keep track of them inside the loop and return a resource collection of them

Okay, so is it the Inventory::create($item) that executes the save to the database?
